# Problems animating bones-paper plane

Tags: animation, bones, vertex-groups

After practicing sculpture, I decided to get into animation and run into a problem. I started practicing animation, but I have a problem.
I chose the bones for this exercise.
The exercise was to make a turn of paper and I wanted it to fly, to do it in other ways, but I had never done it before with bones.
At the time of trying to fly, the plane is deformed very ugly.
Any idea how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: How did you parent the object to the bone? If you did it with Automatic Weight it probably didn't parent well, you can correct that, going to the Vertex Groups panel of your object and removing or assigning the part of the mesh you want to the correct bone

Comment: No, I do not use automatic weight. I painted the weight.
I'll explain.
the animation begins with a sheet of paper folding and becoming an airplane. Until that step everything is fine, but at the time of flying is deformed, which does not happen if you fly in a straight line. This error only occurs when rotating or make curved movements

Comment: hard to understand what's happening, please share your file or take several screenshots

Comment: OF COURSE. 
http://www.mediafire.com/file/iddhxd0xde7ij73/untitled.blend/file
check the last animation, its very troublesome.
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps I miss something but in my opinion your file is uselessly complex as it mixes bones and shape keys, and uses several armatures, so 1) you'd better use only bones and no shape keys 2) you'd better only use only one armature, with one main parent bone to control all the child bones... what do you think about it?

Comment: So, how do I create a bone matrix for those bones?
I am a beginner in animation, I have left the sculpture and I am encouraged to experiment with animation, that is why I chose this exercise.

Comment: You can join all your bones to make a unique armature (ctrl J) or recreate your armature from scratch. In both cases it's better to create an additional big bone which won't have any weight on the mesh but will be the parent of all your bones. To do that you will have to select all your bones, then, at last, the parent bone you have created and ctrl P > Keep Offset. You also have to control that the influence of your bones on the mesh is correct, either in Weight Paint mode, or with Vertex Groups assignments.

Comment: When all this will be finished you can create the wings animation and repeat this animation in loop with the NLA editor, and move the whole armature along a straight line or along a curve with a Follow Path.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all your bones to make a unique armature (ctrl J) or recreate your armature from scratch. In both cases it's better to create an additional big bone which won't have any weight on the mesh but will be the parent of all your bones. To do that you will have to select all your bones, then, at last, the parent bone you have created and ctrl P > Keep Offset. You also have to control that the influence of your bones on the mesh is correct, either in Weight Paint mode, or with Vertex Groups assignments.

When all this will be finished you can create the wings animation and repeat this animation in loop with the NLA editor, and move the whole armature along a straight line or along a curve with a Follow Path.

Comment: Not that you can join them, you totally should.